# variable not assignable missing__block

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Im trying to add a 10 count loop to my game but when i run the code it generates a  "variable not assignable missing__block" error message. Can anyone tell me where i'm going wrong and point me in the right direction?

```
 -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
    CGPoint currentLocation = [[touches anyObject] locationInNode:self];
    CGPoint previousLocation = [[touches anyObject] previousLocationInNode:self];
    CGRect shipRect = _ship.frame;
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(shipRect, previousLocation))
    {
       [self launch:10 p1:currentLocation p2:previousLocation rect1:shipRect];
    }
 }

-(void)launch:(int)count p1:(CGPoint) currentLocation p2:(CGPoint) previousLocation rect1:(CGRect) shipRect
{
    CGPoint lvPosition = CGPointMake(_ship.position.x - (previousLocation.x - currentLocation.x), _ship.position.y);
_ship.position = lvPosition;

    SKAction *sound = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"slideup.mp3" waitForCompletion:NO];
    SKAction *moveNode = [SKAction moveByX:lvPosition.x y:10.0 duration:3.0];

   [_ship runAction: sound];
   [_ship runAction: moveNode completion:^{[self launch:count-- p1:currentLocation p2:previousLocation rect1:shipRect];}]; /*variable not assignable missing__block error*/

}
```

Comment: changing parameters is bad idea, in blocks or not, you should avoid it

Comment: You say you are trying to add a loop, but there is no loop in your code sample. Have you missed something out of your sample by mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are trying to decrement the variable `count` which is not defined as `__block`. You have to declare each variable you want to change inside a block with `__block`, for example `__block int count;`

[EDIT]
in your case the simplest solution is to asign `count-1` to the recursive call, as you do not need the result of `count--` later on

Answer (score 1):

Non-`__block` local variables are not assignable in blocks.

However, making it `__block` is probably not what you want either. The method name `runAction:completion:` sounds like it will call the "completion" block once, after the action finishes. Since it is called once, and `count` is not used thereafter, post-decrementing it is pointless.